# Free CI server hosting or service for JVM based OSS projects

Tags: java, scala, open-source, jvm, continuous-integration

Looking for continuous integration server hosting or service for JVM-based projects which is free for open-source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Travis CI](http://about.travis-ci.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I have had excellent luck with [CloudBees](http://www.cloudbees.com/) which uses Jenkins.  They have their own repository available, or you can use their integration with GitHub, or you can even use it with other external repositories.  I am using it with Google Code.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that we use is [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/).